how would i make it stop for a small amount of time then it keeps scrolling again
https://codepen.io/lucabeingluca/pen/vYMPLZN


.wrapper {
    max-width: 10%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.marquee {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    animation: marquee 7s linear infinite;
}

.marquee p {
    display: inline-block;
}

@keyframes marquee {
    0% {
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
    }
}
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="marquee">
        <p>
            longer one again
        </p>
        <p>
            longer one again
        </p>
    </div>
</div>



I want it to after finishing one "longer one again" it stops for a brief like half second then it keeps scrolling it just repeats kind of like the apple music scroll animation when the title is too long it just starts scrolling then stop for a brief second then keeps going. yk :)
i don't know what to try because im dumb :/

We could add another keyframe at 10% that keeps the position at 0 so nothing changes between 0% and 10%, then scrolls for the rest of the 90% of the animation.


.wrapper {
    max-width: 10%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.marquee {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    animation: marquee 7s linear infinite;
}

.marquee p {
    display: inline-block;
}

@keyframes marquee {
    0% {
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    10% {
        transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
    }
}
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="marquee">
        <p>
            longer one again
        </p>
        <p>
            longer one again
        </p>
    </div>
</div>



